# Antd Charts 2 lines on with an x axis that has different interval values within the same chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, antd

Is it possible to to generate a line chart in Antd from  ('@ant-design/plots') , to plot 2 series' in the same graph, in two different time intervals on X-axis?
e.g.  one series line is to be plotted every 1 min and another one plotted every 15 mins.

e.g. mock json-

const graphData = [
{
"time": "01:00",
"graphType": "15_min",
"SumofDays": 71
},
{
"time": "01:01",
"graphType": "1_min",
"SumofDays": 70.15
},
{
"time": "01:15",
"graphType":"15_min",
"SumofDays": 39.29
},
{
"time": "01:01",
"graphType": "1_min",
"SumofDays": 33.28
},
...

];
Code:

```
const LineChart = (props) => {
  const config = {
    data: graphData,
    xField: 'time',
    yField: 'SumofDays',
    seriesField: 'graphType',
    xAxis: {
      tickCount: 48,
      label: {
        formatter: (v) => {
          const formattedTime = `${v}`.match(/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/g)
          return formattedTime[0];
        }
      }
    },
    series: {
      label: {
        formatter: (v) => `${v}`.replace(/\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, (s) => `${s},`),
      }
    },
  
    width: 480,
    height:  325,
    color: ['#1979C9', '#D62A0D'],
  };
  return <Line {...config} />;


}
```

I want to see both "graphType": "15_min" and "graphType": "1_min" in a single x-axis frame. Please help. Thanks!